# SQL column as select

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

In SQLite and/or MySQL, is it possible to define a column as a `SELECT` statement?

Like the column `Book.NumOfPages` is actually `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PAGES WHERE BOOK_ID=BOOK.ID`, so NumOfPages automatically counts the number of pages assigned to a certain book.

Please note that I know how to get the number of books within one select. I want to know if it's possible to define a select statement as part of a column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, but you have at least following options:

1. Use subquery to define your new column in your SELECT statement (example 1)
2. Wrap your query described in p.1 in outer `SELECT` in order to do joins, grouping, calc an aggregate, etc. (example 2)
3. Create a view based on a query  described in p.1 (example 3)
4. Create a stored procedure the same way
5. And one more option - create a column in a parent table (in your case books) and populate it with triggers INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE on a child table (in your case pages). This denormalizing approach is usually used under very specific circumstances (e.g. when you need to speed up analytic queries).

Example 1

```
SELECT id, `title`, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM pages p 
         WHERE p.book_id = b.id) npages
  FROM books b
```

Output

```
| ID | TITLE | NPAGES |
-----------------------
|  1 | book1 |      3 |
|  2 | book2 |      2 |
```

**[MySql SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83bf6/1)**

**[SQLLite SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/50a66/1)**

Example 2

```
SELECT SUM(npages) total_pages
FROM (SELECT id, `title`, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM pages p 
         WHERE p.book_id = b.id) npages
  FROM books b) t
```

Example 3 Creating a view

```
CREATE VIEW vw_books AS
SELECT id, `title`, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM pages p 
         WHERE p.book_id = b.id) npages
  FROM books b
```

Example 4 Creating a SP

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_books()
BEGIN
SELECT id, `title`, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM pages p 
         WHERE p.book_id = b.id) npages
  FROM books b;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

And use it

```
CALL sp_books();
```

Comment: This is not what I asked. Can I write those directly into the table itself so the column NumOfPages is an alias for a query (i.e. calling NumOfPages always selects something)?

Comment: See updated answer. You have several options. What to use is depends on why do you need it.

Comment: Very well! This is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're thinking of: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(database)

A database view lets you make a "fake" table that consists of queries on other tables. I know it works in MySQL, though I'm not going to make any promises about SQLite.

Comment: So you suggest "hiding" the actual Book-table and accessing it viá a View?

Comment: Not so fast.  First make sure that a view is what you are looking for.  In your example, NumberOfPages would be a column of the view, not of any table.